# Parsing a date using DateTimeFormatter ofPattern

Tags: java, parsing, datetime-format, date-parsing, datetimeformatter

I'm trying to parse a string containing a date and time using the `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` (my ultimate goal is to get the date from this string into a `java.time.LocalDate`).

I keep getting DateTimeParseExceptions when trying to parse the date. Can someone help please?

The date is in the format "2015-07-14T11:42:12.000+01:00".

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
LocalDateTime temp = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.from(f.parse(this.dateCreated)), 
                 ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDate localDate = temp.toLocalDate();
```

I've tried different variations in the ofPattern, such as trying to escape the T by surrounding it with single quotes (as done above), and doing the same with the . and I've tried escaping both at the same time.

Do the colons need escaping too?

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

//or

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
```

instead of

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

From JAVADoc:

> Offset X and x: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern
> letters. One letter outputs just the hour, such as '+01', unless the
> minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as
> '+0130'. Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon,
> such as '+0130'. Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a
> colon, such as '+01:30'. Four letters outputs the hour and minute and
> optional second, without a colon, such as '+013015'. Five letters
> outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as
> '+01:30:15'. Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException.
> Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be
> output would be zero, whereas pattern letter 'x' (lower case) will
> output '+00', '+0000', or '+00:00'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still get an exception with this, when I run a unit test which passes in the above date to this method.

The exception message is "Text '2015-07-14T11:42:07.000+01:00' could not be parsed at index 23".

Is this to do with the single quotes you've put around the Z? As I didnt think these were needed.

Comment: Sorry `Z` should be without single quotes. Also use small `z` as you are separating `hh` & `mm` with `:` in `+01:00`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. :)
I got it to work in the end by using "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX". Don't really understand the difference between X, Z and z though. It worked with three Xs but not one X. Also dont get why three Xs worked, since there are more than 3 characters there.

Comment: You are right to use `XXX` since it is `11:42:12.000+01:00`. I have added the description from JAVADoc in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Both "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ" and "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSVV" would work. Note that 5 Zs work but no less

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2015-07-14T11:42:12.000+01:00" )  // No pattern needed.
```

## No formatting pattern needed

Your input string complies with the ISO 8601 standard for date-time formats.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need for you to define a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2015-07-14T11:42:12.000+01:00" ) ;
```